# package 'libbluray2:amd64' is missing

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libbluray2:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I already tried the usual stuff like:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libbluray2:amd64.list`

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 . ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a corrupted file. You can remove it and install the package again.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libbluray2:amd64.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall libbluray2
```

Comment: golam@Ghostlife:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libbluray2.list
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libbluray2.list': No such file or directory

Comment: I fixed the command.

Comment: thank you so much you just save me.